# Facebook v2.5 SDK issue?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm having problems with the new Facebook API.  All my old accounts work perfectly and today I did a new installation on a site I'm working on.

However, every time I requested details all I got back from Facebook was my User ID and Name.  I thought my SDK was old downloaded the new but it's the same.

I then tested my new App Id and Secret on my older sites just in case and the same result, I don't get any details from public profile or email requested.

Has anyone had any problems with new apps created recently, have they changed something?

My code is

```js
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app_id',
  'app_secret' => 'secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
  ]);


$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email','user_about_me', 'user_likes', 'public_profile']; // optional

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.website.co.uk/triggerFacebook.php', $permissions);


if (isset($accessToken)) {
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
  
  // Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me');
  $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

you have to now request the fields as of 2.5 so on the line

$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email');